# c passing unsigned long long value

Tags: c

How can the last two lines of one function be

```
printf("disk_free_blocks returning %llu\n",item_int3);
return (item_int3);
```

and out put

disk_free_blocks returning 233012428800

returning to calling function as

```
part_avail=disk_free_blocks(DiskParts[part_index].part_name,DISK_AVAIL);
if (DEBUG) printf("DiskParts[%d].part_name=%s has %llu free.\n",part_index,DiskParts[part_index].part_name,part_avail);
```

and output be

DiskParts[0].part_name=/dev/sda1 has 1084194816 free.

??

```
unsigned long long part_avail, item_int3;
```

Comment: Do we have to guess the contents of the rest of the code that you didn't show us? For example the type declarations of all participants in the puzzle. If you don't deem it worthy to include those then I'd say you need look no further. Your task is learn the importance of types in C.

Comment: How is `disk_free_blocks` declared ?

Comment: Obvious question, but your return type for disk_free_blocks is defined as `unsigned long long`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED

`disk_free_blocks()` resided in a different file than `process_copy_out()`, the function making the call to `disk_free_blocks`.

The fix was adding a function prototype to inform the compiler.

Thank you everyone for your help.

Answer (score 5):

The two output numbers are:

```
0x00000036409F8000
```

and

```
        0x409F8000
```

It appears that the return type (which you haven't shown) isn't large enough to accomodate a 64-bit value, so the compiler simply truncates (which is the behavior required by the standard, for narrowing conversions on unsigned integers).

---

I tend to think these are both wrong: 233 billion blocks, with a 512 byte block, that is 100 TB.  Not likely.  1 billion blocks is then around 512 GB, which might or might not match your actual `/dev/sda1` free space.

> ```
> unsigned long long part_avail, item_int3;
> ```

This doesn't make sense, since the usage of these two variables is in different scopes.  Are there two variables with the same name?  Or are you using global variables?

Possibly `item_int3` inside the function is only 32 bits, `printf` reads past the end of the argument list during vararg processing, and the stack just happened to have `0x00000036` on it, so that got printed by the `%llu` specifier.  When returned as an `unsigned long long`, the compiler properly zero-extends the value, and then the caller pushes the full 64-bit value onto the stack, which is retrieved and printed correctly during `printf` vararg processing of the `%llu` format code.

Comment: +1, it's really obvious with the hexadecimal numbers. Well played.

Comment: unsigned long long disk_free_blocks(char *disk,int option) {

Comment: part_avail is declared in calling function, item_int3 in returning function, I pasted as that just to make sure there were no guesses on the two types of params in the code provided

Comment: disk_free_blocks() executes sprintf(command, "/bin/df -B 1 | grep %s ", disk);

Comment: @c card: How did they end up declared on a single line, if they're in two functions?  Do you have two variables with the same name?

Comment: @c card: Why are you calling it the number of free blocks, when it's the number of bytes?

Comment: every time i go to hit return it posts comment instead of give me new line, i apologize, but @ben voigt  * NOTE: The unit block is used throughout the program. A block 
 * is 512 BYTES

Comment: @c card: What's the correct free space (run `/bin/df -h /dv/sda1` in your shell)?

Comment: @ben voigt not declared on same line, declared in two seperate functions, in two seperate files... only displayed here on site this way in an effort to make it easier for audience but that seems to have backfired. lesson learned

Comment: @c card: If you can't figure out the behavior yourself, it probably is affected by some small detail.

Comment: ~# /bin/df -B 1 | grep /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1            246131359744 616095744 233012428800   1% /b

Comment: @c card: That would have been much more readable if you'd used `df -h` like I suggested, but now at least we know that the correct free space is 233GB.  What compiler are you using?  I know several versions of printf where the correct way to print a 64-bit unsigned is `%I64u`.  Also, if this is gnu `df`, you can pass the device to `df` and you wouldn't need to use `grep`.  It should also be faster, not having to access all filesystems.

Comment: @ben voigt apologies again, the print is one thing, but what brought me to the bug is 
    if (part_avail < dirData[dir_index].dir_size){
failing when i know there is plenty of space....

Comment: @c card: Do you get the same truncation if you comment out everything inside `disk_free_blocks` and just `return 233012428800ULL;`?

Answer (score 1):

The return value was truncated to 32 bits somewhere along the way. Perhaps `disk_free_blocks` is declared as returning an `int`?

Comment: unsigned long long disk_free_blocks(char *disk,int option) {